# Java, impossible cast Object to Float.....why?

Tags: java, casting, floating-point

Why this works:

```
 Object prova = 9.2;
 System.out.println(prova);
 Double prova2 = (Double) prova;
 System.out.println(prova2);
```

And this doesn't?

```
Object prova = 9.2;
System.out.println(prova);
Float prova2 = (Float) prova;
System.out.println(prova2);
```

I lost 1 hour in my java android application cause of this thing so i had to cast it in a double and than the double in a float or i had an exception

Comment: If you read the exception text from the latter (which I'm assuming is `ClassCastException`), and then look at the inheritance hierarchy for `Float` and `Double`, the answer should be apparent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because you are relying on autoboxing when you wrote

```
Object prova = 9.2;
```

If you want it to be a Float, try

```
Object prova = 9.2f;
```

Remember that java.lang.Float and java.lang.Double are sibling types; the common type is java.lang.Number

If you want to express a Number in whatever format, use the APIs, for example [Number.floatValue()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#floatValue%28%29)

Answer (score 18):

Because `prova` is a `Double`, and **`Double` is not a subtype of `Float`**.

Either you could start with a float literal: `9.2f` (in which case `prova` would actually be a `Float`) or, you could  it like this:

```
Float prova2 = ((Double) prova).floatValue();
```

Answer (score 15):

`9.2` is a double literal. Try `9.2f` instead.

```
Object prova = 9.2f; // float literal is auto-boxed to a Float
System.out.println(prova);
Float prova2 = (Float) prova; // Float can be cast to Float, while Double cannot
System.out.println(prova2);
```

The error message (which you probably should have included in your question) explains it quite well also:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
```

Comment: You can also check what is happening by adding `System.out.println(prova.getClass());`

Answer (score 2):

Because if you don't specify, it will be a double.  If you want it to be a float, you need

```
Object prova = 9.2F;
System.out.println(prova);
Float prova2 = (Float) prova;
System.out.println(prova2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Casting it as ***Float*** not ***float***
Simple

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hit this problem too and it took me a very long time to come up with this very simple solution.
For anyone else who hits this problem and you may not want to or have access to changing the object you are receiving, an alternative to converting object values is to first convert your Double value to a double variable type. Then simply cast double to float... Examples:

(I have not tested this but made this based on the initial posted problem)

```
Object prova = 9.2;
System.out.println(prova);
double dblValProva = prova;
float pova2 = (float) dblValProva ;
System.out.println(prova2);
```

(This is an example that I was working with myself, hope these examples can help others in future)

```
JSONArray color // This is a JSON array containing 3 values... 
//for instance [ 0.501, 0.501, 0.0 ]
double r = (Double) color.get(0);
double g = (Double) color.get(1);
double b = (Double) color.get(2);
Color3f floorColor = new Color3f((float)r, (float)g, (float)b);
```

For me this previously was giving errors when I tried to use:

```
Color3f((float)color.get(0), (float)color.get(1), (float)color.get(2))
```